# The function $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

I'm trying to prove that

> The function $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}$.

Here's what I've done:

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.

Now, $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y|=\Big|\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right) \Big|$$

For non-negative $x,y\in \Bbb{R},$

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y|=\Big|\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right) \Big|\leq |\tan^{-1}(x-y)|\leq|x-y|<\delta$$

We can choose $\epsilon=\delta$. Now, for negative $x,y\in \Bbb{R}$. Please, how do I go about it?

Comment: I am afraid that any attempt to prove that claim is doomed to fail.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen: Then, what should I do?

Comment: What you have started on seems to be to prove that it *is* uniformly continuous... Continue with that!

Comment: Actually,  this function  is uniformly continuous because of the limits $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=\frac{-\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @ Piquito I did  not say “continuous and bounded  implies uniform continuous.” I mean the existence of limits implies uniform continuous!!!!! OK???

Comment: @ Piquito For your example, both the two limits do not exist!

Comment: You are right I misunderstood your comment. I have put your first upvote. It wasn't necessary your three ???. I delete my comment. Regards.

Comment: @Riemann: Exactly, both the two limits do not exist! (from this the counterexample)

Comment: @ Piquito Sorry to three ???. Actually I didn't mean to offend you！Only just to emphasize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $\tan^{-1}x$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb{R}$.

By the Mean Value Theorem, for any $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$,
$$|\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y|\leq |x-y|.$$
So for any $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta=\epsilon>0$, when $|x-y|<\delta$, we have 
$$|\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y|\leq |x-y|<\delta=\epsilon.
$$

Comment: Your first inequality it would be enough. Regards.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no need to say any word!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in another way, that, find its derivative and observe that derivative is bounded then use LMVT to conclude the uniform continuity